# D3DFVF_XYZRHW directx fvf format

Tags: directx

vertex struct

```
struct Vertex
{
    float x, y, z;
    float rhw;
    D3DCOLOR diffuse;
    float u, v;
    Vertex(){}
    Vertex(float px, float py, D3DCOLOR pdiffuse, float pu, float pv)
    {
        x = px; y = py; z = 0.0f;
        rhw = 1.0f;
        diffuse = pdiffuse;
        u = pu; v = pv;
    }
    static const DWORD FVF;
};
const DWORD Vertex::FVF = D3DFVF_XYZRHW | D3DFVF_DIFFUSE | D3DFVF_TEX1;
```

vertex data

```
lpVbData[0] = Vertex(0.0f, 0.0f, 0xFF000000, 0.0f, 0.0f);
lpVbData[1] = Vertex(20.0f, 0.0f, 0xFF000000, 1.0f, 0.0f);
lpVbData[2] = Vertex(20.0f, 100.0f, 0xFF000000, 1.0f, 1.0f);
lpVbData[3] = Vertex(0.0f, 100.0f, 0xFF000000, 0.0f, 1.0f);
```

**My question is
The rect's size should be 20x100(width x height) pixels, but in display is 20x97(width x height) pixels.Why?Thanks.**

Comment: This depends on your projection-matrix and your outputwindow. How do you created the matrix? What is the size of of your directx surface? Do you use a vertexshader or the fixed function pipeline?

Comment: How did you measure your rect in display?

Comment: I use the screenshot software, and meausure the screenshot jpg file in photoshop.
Another way, use the win32 api, set the mouse's pos in client area, at the x:20 y:100 pixel position.

Comment: I use the fixed function pipeline.
The fvf is D3DFVF_XYZRHW, so it willnot be transformed by matrix in pipeline and vertex shader.

Comment: Maybe it has something to do with the Texel/Pixel-Mapping: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb219690%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem has been solved.
the backbuffer size dose not matching the window size, ignore the window's frame, so the backbuffer surface be scaled in window, and the display's pixel size is not correct.